# Is Function call with less no of provided arguments, than needed in the function possible?

Tags: c++

I'm making a single function, which can add up to 4 integers. everything will work fine if I pass 4 int arguments to the function and the function will add them. but if I pass less number of arguments the compiler gives an error.
So I want to ask is there any possible method by which we can give less number of arguments to a function than defined and the function still performs it's task on the given arguments?.

for example (a single function can add upto max 4 integers. but if given 3 arguments it'll still add them)
Nromal/Max:

```
int a=5,b=6,c=7,d=8;
int sum (a,b,c,d);
```

Less no of arg:
'''

```
int a=5,b=6,c=7;
int sum(a,b,c)
```

OUTPUT:
nomral/max= 26
less no of arg= 18;
P.S: here sum function is a single function which outputs the sum of the given int aurguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just give another answer, if the number of arguments shall be fixed (i.e. 4 in your case), you can also use something like

```
int sum(int a, int b = 0, int c = 0, int d = 0) {
    return a + b + c + d; 
}
```

The arguments `b, c, d` are then considered to be "variable". In fact, this function initializes these arguments as `0`, if not given.

An example would be:

```
int S1 = sum(4) // returns 4
int S2 = sum(4, 2) // initialzies b = 2 and returns 6
int S3 = sum(4, 3, 4) // initializes b = 3, c = 4 and returns 11
int S4 = sum(4, b, 3, 4) // won't compile, b is unknown
```

Note, that if you use it in different casees, the optional arguments must be provided in the correct sequence (in contrast to python, where you can specify the variables in the function call)

Comment: while the upper comment was useful, your solution  was specifically what I was looking for.Thankyou.

Comment: It is also worthwhile to note, that the solution of @n314159 would be the better in your case. This method, however, can be used with various types of arguments (in which it makes more sense to choose this variant). E.g. consider your sum as arithmetic mean, it would then have the additional argument `bool isArithmetic = false`.

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy way to do this in C++17 with fold expressions:

```
template<class... Args>
auto sum(Args... args) {
    return args + ... + 0;
}
```

You will be able to call this with an arbitrary number of arguments that are addable (for example you can mix integers and floatingpoints). The `Args...` is called a template parameter pack and the `args + ... + 0` basically expands to `firstarg + secondarg + ... + lastarg + 0` (The zero is there for the case that you pass 0 arguments.)

Comment: There are tricks to mimic fold expressions for C++11/C++14.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, but which changes call site, is to pass argument as "list":

```
int sum(std::initializer_list<int> ini)
{
    return std::accumulate(ini.begin(), ini.end(), 0);
}
```

With usage:

```
int S0 = sum({});
int S1 = sum({a});
int S2 = sum({a, b});
int S3 = sum({a, b, c});
int S4 = sum({a, b, c, d});
```